# Creating a round border around user avatar in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI app, I'm using the `AvatarView` in.NET MAUI Community Toolkit to create a nicely round user avatar which is pretty easy to do.

I now want to put a nice border around the image but I'm not getting the desired effect because when I set the `BorderWidth` property of the `AvatarView`, it places the border "inside" the image which makes the visible area smaller. I actually want to put the border "outside" the image so that I don't lose anything from the visible area. Here's an image that demonstrates this:

[image]

BTW, I tried setting the `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequst` larger and then setting the `BorderWidth` but it still seems to make the visible area smaller because all that's doing is that it makes the main image larger and with the border set, the visible area still doesn't show the additional data/area.

Here's my current code which places the border within the image -- which I can safely assume is the standard behavior.

```
<mct:AvatarView
     ImageSource="{Binding UserInfo.AvatarUrl}"
     BorderColor="{StaticResource UILightGray}"
     BorderWidth="10"
     CornerRadius="70"
     HeightRequest="140"
     WidthRequest="140"/>
```

How do I achieve the effect that I want? Basically, I'd like the border to go outside of the image, effectively adding some 10 pixels to the size of the image.

Alternatively, I don't mind placing the border within the image but I need a way to make the actual image 10 pixel smaller so that the visible area stays the same.

How can I achieve this by using or not using .NET MAUI Community Toolkit?

Comment: Maybe wrap it in a [`Border`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-7.0)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't want to use the community toolkit package, then wrap the `image` with a `Frame` would be a trade-off for this scenario. And also you need to set the **Aspect** of the image to `AspectFit`.

```
            <Frame HeightRequest="140"
                   WidthRequest="140"
                   CornerRadius="70"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   IsClippedToBounds="True"
                   Padding="0"
                   BorderColor="Gray"
                   Margin="0,0,0,0">

                <Image
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                    HeightRequest="140"
                    WidthRequest="140"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Frame>
```

**Update:**

You can also wrap a Border as Steve suggested.

```
      <Border HeightRequest="160" 
                    WidthRequest="160"
                    StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 80,80,80,80"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    
                    StrokeThickness="8"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0">

                <Image
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                    SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                  
                    HeightRequest="160"
                    WidthRequest="160"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Border>
```